# when typecasting a memory pointed by char pointer to unsigned integer , the value coming is not as expected

Tags: c

I am creating three structures:

```
struct ethernet {
    uint16_t dest_mac;
};

struct ip {
    uint16_t src_ip;
    uint16_t dest_ip;
};

struct udp {
    uint16_t porten I
};
```

then I am creating the instances oh the structures and copying then in a char buffer.

```
memcpy(buffer , eth , sizeof(struct ethernet));
    memcpy(buffer + sizeof(struct ethernet) , ipe , sizeof(struct ip));
    memcpy((buffer + sizeof(struct ethernet) + sizeof(struct ip)) , udpe , sizeof(struct udp));
```

Now I define another structure:

```
struct pattern {
    uint64_t pttn;
};
```

now I typecasting the memory pointed by char buffer defined above to struct pattern.

```
struct pattern *pat = NULL;
pat = (struct pattern *)buffer;
```

When I am doing this opertaion the value for pat->pttn is not coming as expected.

Example:

when I am passing values: dest_mac = 1 , src_ip = 2 , dest_ip = 3 , port = 4. The value of pat->pttn is coming out to be 131073 . According to me the value should come is : 281483566841860

Comment: Is `buffer` large enough? And you're breaking strict-aliasing.

Comment: totalSize = sizeof(struct pattern) + sizeof(struct ethernet) + sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct udp);

 buffer = (char *) malloc(totalSize);

Comment: I dont know what do you mean by strict- aliasing.

Comment: You do now: [**What is the strict aliasing rule?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: i guess yout bit manipulating? How do you print your output?

Comment: 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0011 0000 0000 0000 0100 - your bits.

Comment: yes the conversion of (0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0011 0000 0000 0000 0100 ) from binary to decimal will evaluate to 281483566841860 . But the value coming is  131073 , which is 100000000000000001. I am not able to understand how are these values coming.

Comment: It may behoove you to validate the actual size of each of those structures with some debug output. You may find yourself surprised.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a 64bit [unsigned] Integer, being composed from 4 neighboring 16bit integers is system architecture dependent, and depends on the "endianness" of the architecture.